# Why can't I view HLS in Video-js?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js, http-live-streaming

I use [video-js](http://videojs.com/) player, but I can't view [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) in it.

I loaded `videojs-contrib-hls`, but it didn't help.

> The media could not be loaded, either the server or network failed or
>   because the format is not supported.

I have these two lines in the `<head>`:

```
<link href="vjs.zencdn.net/5.9.2/video-js.css"; rel="stylesheet">
<script src="vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
```

In `<body>`:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" style= "width:100%; height:100%" data-setup="{}"> 
    <source src="fambox.tv:1935/vod/smil:1. PK_Film_HD.mp4.smil/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"> 
</video>
```

Comment: Could you provide a description of the error you're getting and how you're doing this with the important parts of your code?

Comment: I have these two line in head 
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.9.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>

and in body 

<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" style= "width:100%; height:100%"
   data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://fambox.tv:1935/vod/smil:1. PK_Film_HD.mp4.smil/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
   

  
  </video>

Comment: I added specific tags and references, block quote error msg, rearrange and clean mal-pasted code from comments, fix grammar and spelling. hope the question is clear. is that `src` right? I don't think there should be a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add videojs hls library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.5.3/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
```

[enter link description here](https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/)

Answer (score 0):

That video source will not play in the video js player. You can try it for yourself here.

https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/

You can see that there are Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) errors that are likely preventing playback.